# Row equivalence implies independent columns?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I need to prove that "given" two matrices are row equivalent, a set of columns of the first matrix are linearly independent iff the corresponding columns of the second matrix are linearly independent.
Any hints / insights would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

- The matrices $A$ and $B$ are row equivalent if and only if $A = RB$ for some invertible matrix $R$
- The columns of a matrix $A$ are linearly independent if and only if for column vectors $x$, $Ax = 0$ implies that $x = 0$.

Comment: So I could say that Ax = 0 => RBx = 0 => Bx = 0 as R is invertible and hence the two have the same solution?

Comment: Yep, that will do it.